# In search of help filtering ansible stdout_lines

Tags: ansible, cisco-ios

I have a group of switches that users keep asking me to locate mac address for in order to trace down the exact port and edit that port to a new vlan. Rather than logging into each switch and tracking down the switch where the mac resides, I created an ansible a basic ansible playbook to help me with this:

```
---
- name: Find mac address in sec-switches
  hosts: sec-switch
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars_prompt:
     - name: mac
       prompt: What is the mac address?
       private: no
  tasks:
    -
      name: debugging
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: 'Searching for {{ mac }}'
    -
      name: "search"
      register: output
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - "show mac address-table | include {{ mac }}"
    -
      debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

When ran, my debug gives me:
(snippet)

```
}
ok: [10.1.1.32] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "24    0050.f967.5cb7    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/48"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [10.1.1.33] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "24    0050.f967.5cb7    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/48"
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [10.1.1.30] => {
    "output.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "4    0050.f967.5cb7    DYNAMIC     Gi1/1/1",
            " 24    0050.f967.5cb7    DYNAMIC     Gi1/1/1"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'd like to filter the output and for each switch run the sh interfaces description | inc { using the returned interfaces}. This way I can rule out uplinks.

IE:  On switch 10.1.1.33 I ran: sh interfaces description | inc Gi1/0/48
and it returned: Gi1/0/48                       up             up       UPLINK

That lets me know I don't need to worry about that switch as its an uplink.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to filter the output of output.stdout_lines to only show the 4th entry of the output:
So for this output: "24    0050.f967.5cb7    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/48"
Is there a way for it to just show: "Gi1/0/48"
If it can do that, can I set that as a fact and the run:
ios_command:
commands:
- "show sh interfaces description | inc {{registered fact}}"

Any help would be appreciated. I looked into https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting closer:     -
      name: "search"
      register: output
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - "show mac address-table | include {{ mac }}"
      register: printout
    - set_fact:
        intf: |
          {{printout.stdout_lines[0] |
            map('regex_replace','^(?:[^ ]*\ ){12}([^ ]*)') |
            list }}
    - name: View output
      debug:
        var: intf

Answer (score 0):

The final piece of the puzzle came from rajthecomputerguy:

Use strip() method to get rid of whitespace

```
  debug:
    var: intf[0].strip()
```

Full code:

```
---

- name: Find mac address in sec-switches

  hosts: sec-switch

  gather_facts: false

  connection: local

  vars_prompt:

     - name: mac

       prompt: What is the mac address?

       private: no

  tasks:

    -

      name: debugging

      ansible.builtin.debug:

        msg: 'Searching for {{ mac }}'

    -

      name: search

      ios_command:

        commands:

          - "show mac address-table | include {{ mac }}"

      register: printout

    - set_fact:

        intf: |

          {{printout.stdout_lines[0] |

            map('regex_replace','^(?:[^ ]*\ ){12}([^ ]*)') |

            list }}

    -

      name: show int desc

      ios_command:

        commands:

          - "sh interfaces description | inc {{ intf[0].strip() }}"

      register: printout2

    - name: View output

      debug:

        var: printout2
```